# Angular errors: Getting syntax errors on the routes and another saying the module wont load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
1
​
2
​
3
    'use strict';   
4
​
5
     var app = angular.module('zooMarket',['ngRoute'])
7
​
8
      .config(function ($routeProvider){
9
       $routeProvider
10
      .when('/',{
11
        templateUrl:'index.html'
12
          });     
13
          .when('/post',{
14
            templateUrl:'views/login.html'
15
          });
16
          .when('/edit',{
17
            templateUrl:'views/edit.html'
18
          });
19
          .when('/browse',{
20
            templateUrl:'views/browse.html'
21
          });
22
           .otherwise({
23
            redirectTo:'/'
24
           });
25
          });
26
​
```

> Preserve log . app.js:13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
>   angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=zooMarket&p1=Error…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.15%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

Comment: Please format your code appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.when(...);` you have to use `.when(...).when` to chain methods. Simply, remove semicolons before each `when` call.

Answer (score 0):

We guess you are pretty new to JS, so try to learn how to use linters and learn what they are.

[This link will prevent you from syntax errors](http://eslint.org/demo/)

Comment: Max..thank you for formatting the page. Appeiron I am not new to Javascript. Still getting the same syntax errors.

Comment: Probably you need some better ide that will mark syntax errors better. Did you installed linter plugins? That ; such obvious, it would be marked with eslint plugin in subtext 3 or in webstorm

Answer (score 0):

why you terminate chain expression:

```
    .when('/edit',{

        templateUrl:'views/edit.html'

      })

      .when('/browse',{

        templateUrl:'views/browse.html'

      })

       .otherwise({

        redirectTo:'/'

       });
```